# Test predictability with Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Say we have a disease and a test for it.
P(A :=a person has the disease)= 0.01 ( example)
P( B:=test is positive | A )=0.95
Is this enough information to calculate the probability that a person has the disease given that his test came back positive?
I've seen quite a lot of solved exercises taking Baye's theorem and assuming (without even mentioning it) that P(B|A') is 0.05.Is it correct?
Is there any other way to find the probability or do we need to know more?

Comment: You need to know more.  Specifically, you need to know the probability that a person without the disease tests positive. to take an extreme case, suppose every single person without the disease tests positive.  Then a positive test result will have very little meaning (though, oddly, a negative result would prove that the person had the disease).

Answer (score 0):

You need to know more.

For problems like these, it is always good to take particular examples, even extreme examples.

In what follows assume that, in Reality, $1\%$ of the population has the disease.

Example A:  A person without the disease NEVER tests positive.  In that case, a positive test result is absolute proof that the person actually has the disease.

Example B:  A person without the disease has a $5\%$ chance of testing positive.  Given our assumptions that means that $.95\%$ of the population has the disease AND tests positive for it.  It also means that $4.95\%$ of the population does not have the disease BUT tests positive for it.  In this case a person who tests positive will actually have the disease with probability $$\frac {.95}{4.95+.95}\sim 16.1\%$$

Example C: (caricature example) A person without the disease ALWAYS tests positive for it.  In that case we still have that $.95\%$ of the population has the disease AND tests positive for it, but now we have that $99\%$ of the population does not have the disease BUT tests positive for it.  In that (admittedly extreme) situation the probability that a person who tests positive will actually have the disease is $$\frac {.95}{99+.95}\sim .95\%$$